# How can I get my MapView annotations to save when I leave the app?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation

```
func addPin(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
    let locCoord = self.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = locCoord
    annotation.title = titleTextField.text

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    print("This will become the annotation title: \(titleTextField.text).")
    print(annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude)

}
```

I am new to swift and would like to know how to get my annotations to save after leaving the app. Also, how do I stop multiple annotations from forming if the user does not pick up their finger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll likely need to do is store the `MKPointAnnotation`s as `Data` within `UserDefaults`. To do this, you'll create an array of dictionaries from all of the mapView's annotations:

```swift
func addPin(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
    let locCoord = self.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = locCoord
    annotation.title = titleTextField.text

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    //Create a dictionary from the annotation
    let newAnnotationDict = [
        "lat": locCoord.latitude
        "lng": locCoord.longitude
        "title": annotation.title
    ]

    //Pull the stored annotations data
    var annotationsArray: [[String:Any]]!
    var annotationsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "StoredAnnotations")

    //If the data is nil, then set the new annotation as the only element in the array
    if annotationsData == nil {
        annotationsArray = [newAnnotationDict]
    } else {
        //If it isn't nil, then convert the data into an array of dicts
        do {
            //Convert this data into an array of dicts
            annotationsArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: annotationsData, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
            annotationsArray.append(newAnnotationDict)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    do {

        //Use JSONSerialization to convert the annotationsArray into Data
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: annotationsArray, options: .prettyPrinted)

        //Store this data in UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.set(jsonData, forKey: "StoredAnnotations")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    print("This will become the annotation title: \(titleTextField.text).")
    print(annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude)

}
```

And then, when the view controller is opened again, you'll want to pull this `Data` from `UserDefaults` and parse it into an array of `MKPointAnnotation` objects.

```swift
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    //Whenever the view loads, check if there were any annotations stored last time
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Check if the data for "StoredAnnotations" exists
        if UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "StoredAnnotations") != nil {

            var storedAnnotationObjects = [MKPointAnnotation]()

            do {

                //Get the data from UserDefaults
                let storedAnnotationsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "StoredAnnotations")!

                //Convert this data into an array of dictionaries
                let storedAnnotationsArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: storedAnnotationsData, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]

                for dict in storedAnnotationsArray {
                    //Initialize a new annotation and set the annotation's properties
                    let newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    newAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dict["lat"] as! CGFloat, longitude: dict["lng"] as! CGFloat)
                    newAnnotation.title = dict["title"] as! String
                    newAnnotationObjects.append(newAnnotation)
                }

                //Add the annotation to the mapView
                self.mapView.annotations = storedAnnotationObjects
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

If annotations are being removed, you'll need to similarly convert the stored data into an array of dicts and remove the appropriate object and update the data.

Comment: Thank you, that works well. However, if I wanted to save every annotation the user has made rather than just the previous one, how would I do that?

Comment: Similarly, instead of storing a single dict as data to user defaults, you could loop through all of your annotations and create an array of dicts, each dict representing an individual annotation. It would essentially be converting your mapView's `annotations` array into a json and storing it locally. Upon opening the view controller again, you can parse it into an array of annotations. Perhaps later I can update the code to work for multiple annotations.

Comment: Okay, @MichaelStangas, I updated the code to reflect how you would do this with multiple annotations. You're basically storing an array of dicts instead of just a single dict, but the concept remains the same. I haven't tested this code, but it should be pretty accurate. Just let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: With a few tweaks, it worked great! Lastly, I originally had a "delete all" button that cleared the map of annotations. Although it still works, when returning to the page, the annotations reappear b/c they are stored in UserDefaults. How would I clear the map by deleting them from UserDefaults? Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Im glad it helped. To delete what's stored in the user defaults, you could simply set the value of "StoredAnnotations" to `nil` via `UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "StoredAnnotations")`. You'll notice we have a check to see if this stored value in `UserDefaults` is `nil` and, if it is, we make our annotations array an array with a single element: the newly created annotation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many strategies for persistence on iOS and depend on many factors like how many annotations will you save, how sensitive is the data, etc.

Apple's persistence guide is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html

You might be able to get away serializing the objects themselves though I don't really suggest this. Instead, consider writing your own annotation type that conforms to `Codable` to make persistence safer and easier. This tutorial does a reasonable job of covering your use case:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5247-core-location-tutorial-for-ios-tracking-visited-locations#toc-anchor-022

It's annoying that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not `Codable` itself, which is why you have to jump through some hoops.

Comment: Thank you for the info!